# What is the maximum simultaneous HTTP connections allowed on one machine (windows server 2008) using python

Tags: python

To be more specific, I'm using python and making a pool of HTTPConnection (httplib) and was wondering if there is an limit on the number of concurrent HTTP connections on a windows server.

Comment: Say, could I create 1000 simultaneous connections to the same server? without impacting the performance.

Comment: Why don't you simply try to create 1000 connections and see what happens?

Comment: I did, at the 1000 connections slowed down ~500ms/requests. On 10 connections, I'm at ~10 ms

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of how many are allowed, it's more like how many do you need, or how many can you use efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html), a client should not maintain more than 2 simultaneous connections to a webserver or proxy. However, most browsers don't honor that - firefox 3.5 allows 6 per server and 8 per proxy.

In short, you should not be opening 1000 connections to a single server, unless your intent *is* to impact the performance of the server. Stress testing your server would be a good legitimate example.

---

[Edit]
If this is a proxy you're talking about, then that's a little different story. My suggestion is to use connection pooling. Figure out how many simultaneous connections give you the most requests per second and set a hard limit. Extra requests just have to wait in a queue until the pool frees up. Just be aware than a single process is usually capped at 1024 file descriptors by default.

Take a look through [apache's mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) for ideas on how to handle this.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the RFC you mention? Is it the HTTP RFC?

Comment: I probably should have added that, instead just trying to sound authoritative :)

Comment: I don't want to stress test my server. The real problem is that my server is load balanced and can take >2000 requests/seconds. But now we need all the requests to pass by a "proxy" server and that proxy server creates a new connection per request received by the client.

So now, we're stuck with this design and have to do it in python. :(

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the numbers of internet sockets (necessary to make TCP/IP connections) is naturally limited on every machine, but it's pretty high. 1000 simulatneous connections shouldn't be a problem for the client machine, as each socket uses only little memory. If you start receiving data through all these channels, this might change though. I've heard of test setups that created a couple of thousands connections simultaneously from a single client.

The story is usually different for the server, when it does heavy lifting for each incoming connection (like forking off a worker process etc.). 1000 incoming connections *will* impact its performance, and coming from the same client they can easily be taken for a DoS attack. I hope you're in charge of both the client and the server... or is it the same machine?